# Infinitesimal transformations and Poisson bracket for Dirac spinors

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, dirac-equation, spinors, poisson-brackets

I apologize for the cumbersome calculations.

Let's have $\Psi$, $i\Psi^{\dagger}$, which are canonical coordinate and impulse in space of solutions of Dirac equation. It can be showed that they have infinitesimal transformations
$$
\delta \Psi = \frac{1}{2}\omega^{\mu \nu}\eta_{\mu \nu}\Psi , \quad i\delta \Psi^{\dagger} = -\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{+}\gamma^{0}\eta_{\mu \nu}\gamma^{0}, \quad \eta_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{4}(\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu} - \gamma_{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}), \qquad (.1)
$$
and $\omega^{\mu \nu}$ are local coordinates of the Lorentz group in bispinor representation.

I wanted to use Poisson's (i.e., introducing Poisson's bracket with all convenient 
consequences) formalism for Dirac equation. So after introducing Poisson's brackets
$$
[A, B]_{P} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial \Psi}\frac{\partial B}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}} - \frac{\partial A}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}}\frac{\partial B}{\partial \Psi}
$$
I also decided to introduce generating function for canonical transformations (I have problem with them; see the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81205/how-to-introduce-generating-function-in-hamiltonian-formalism-for-field-theories)). For function $F(\Psi , i\Psi^{+}{'})$ the canonical equations are following:
$$
\Psi {'} = \frac{\partial F}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}{'}}, \quad i \Psi^{\dagger} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial \Psi}.
$$ 
So for infinitesimal transformations
$$
F = \Psi i\Psi^{\dagger}{'} + G(\Psi , i\Psi^{\dagger}{'}),
$$
where $G$ is called generator, I got
$$
\Psi{'} = \Psi + \frac{\partial G}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}{'}} \approx \Psi + \frac{\partial G}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}}, \quad i\Psi^{+} = i\Psi^{\dagger}{'} +\frac{\partial G}{\partial \Psi}  \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
\delta \Psi = \frac{\partial G}{i\partial \Psi^{+}}, \quad i\delta \Psi^{\dagger} = -\frac{\partial G}{\partial \Psi} \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\delta \Psi = [\Psi , G]_{P}, \quad i\delta \Psi^{\dagger} = [i\Psi^{\dagger}, G]_{P}. \qquad (.2)
$$
As result I can get the generator for $(.1)$ by using $(.2)$.

For $\delta \Psi$,
$$
\frac{\partial G}{i\partial \Psi^{\dagger}} = \frac{1}{2}\omega^{\mu \nu}\eta_{\mu \nu}\Psi, \qquad (.3)
$$
for $i\delta \Psi^{\dagger}$,
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial \Psi} = -\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}\eta_{\mu \nu}\gamma^{0}. \qquad (.4)
$$
Then I expected that the density of the generators of the Lorentz group in bispinor case, which [has](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80638/spin-tensor-and-lorentz-group-operator-in-bispinor-case) the expression
$$
i\omega\Psi^{\dagger}\eta_{\mu \nu}\Psi ,
$$
can be naturally interpreted as the generator of infinitesimal transformations. So by substituning it into $(.2)$ I got
$$
\delta \Psi = \frac{1}{2}\omega^{\mu \nu}\eta_{\mu \nu}\Psi , \quad i\delta\Psi^{\dagger} \neq -\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}\eta_{\mu \nu}\gamma^{0} ,
$$
which contradicts with $(.3), (.4)$. Also, it seems that system $(.3), (.4)$ doesn't have solution.

Where is the mistake?

**An addition.**

My attempt to solve $(.3), (.4)$.

From $(.3)$ I can get
$$
G = \frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\eta_{\mu \nu}\Psi + G_{1}(\Psi)
$$
and by substituting it in $(.4)$ it follows that
$$
-\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\eta_{\mu \nu} - \partial_{\Psi}G_{1} = -\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\gamma_{0}\eta_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{0}.
$$ 
It is possible to transform the right part of this expression by using commutator 
$$
[\gamma_{0}, \eta_{\mu \nu}] = \frac{1}{2}\left( g_{0 \nu}\gamma_{\mu} - g_{0\mu}\gamma_{\nu}\right):
$$
$$
-\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\eta_{\mu \nu} - \partial_{\Psi}G_{1} = -\frac{i\omega^{\mu \nu}}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\eta_{\mu \nu} - i\omega^{\mu 0}\gamma_{\mu},
$$
so
$$
\partial_{\Psi}G_{1}(\Psi) = i\omega^{\mu 0}\Psi^{\dagger}\gamma_{\mu},
$$
which leads to the problems.

Comment: By $\Psi^+$ did you mean $\Psi^\dagger$? Or is it a completely separate quantity?

Comment: @DavidZ . I meaned hermitian conjugate to $\Psi$ bispinor. So Dirac conjurated bispinor is $\bar \Psi = \Psi^{+}\gamma^{0}$.

Comment: OK, gotcha. That would normally be indicated as `\Psi^\dagger`, $\Psi^\dagger$. Perhaps you'd like to edit accordingly.